# Are blocks stored in blkxxxxx.dat files per line?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, raw-data, chainanalysis

Simple question. Is each line in a blkxxxxx.dat file a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: no.

The files are not text files and therefore don't have lines.

Comment: So the only way to parse it is to check each block size in order to skip to the next?

Comment: Tested and confirmed!